# Invoke directly lambda vs SNS trigger lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

In case of a event driven serverless stack with a HTTPS call in a Rest API and the trigger of another lambda to answer in a Websocket API, **what is the best solution between SNS lambda trigger or aws sdk invoke in a asynchronus event architecture?**

[image: lambda invoke VS SNS trigger]

I can clearly see why choosing aws sdk invoke:

- No need to implement another service, easier
- Invoke is made by direct invoke from the code of lambda (fast, no duplicates, ...)

**So I can't see the usefullness of adding SNS in between insted of a lot more configuration.**

Just for more information, the second lambda is like a microservice to answer on websocket.

Comment: Using an Amazon SNS topic is advantageous if you want something else to trigger at the same time (eg another Lambda function). This can be useful if your system will expand in future and might need additional handling of the same event. Otherwise, there's no particular advantage.

Comment: This topic is covered in this well known article: https://theburningmonk.com/2020/07/are-lambda-to-lambda-calls-really-so-bad/